# Get updated User from Firebase Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working with Firebase. At the moment I'm using `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1`

Creating a user, Sign-In works like a charm.

Now I want to add an option for the user where it's possible for the user to change his/her displayName and profileImage

In Activity A I call this method, by clicking a button:

```
   public void updateFirebaseUser(String newDisplayName, Uri newPhotoUri) {
      final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      final FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
      if (user == null || (TextUtils.isEmpty(newDisplayName) && newPhotoUri == null)) {
         return;
      }
      UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder builder = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder();

      if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(newDisplayName)) {
         builder.setDisplayName(newDisplayName);
      }
      if (newPhotoUri != null) {
         builder.setPhotoUri(newPhotoUri);
      }
      UserProfileChangeRequest request = builder.build();
      user.updateProfile(request)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                  Toast.makeText(context, "profile update success = " + task.isSuccessful(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
               }
            });
   }
```

Everything seems to work, because I receive the Toast on my screen, which shows `"profile update success = true"`

Later in the app I want to display the user info, I call `fillUserViews()` in Activity B. **But still my old information is displayed.**

```
   private void fillUserViews(NavigationView navigationView) {
      View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
      FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

      ImageView avatarVIew = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.img_avatar);
      picasso.load(user.getPhotoUrl())
            .into(avatarVIew);

      TextView userName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
      userName.setText(user.getDisplayName());

      TextView userMail = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_mail);
      userMail.setText(user.getEmail());
   }
```

Also restarting the app doesn't help here. But if I logout and re-login again my user data is updated.

I think this has something to do with the Firebase internal caching. That's why I added this line `auth.getCurrentUser().reload();` after showing the the toast.

Is there a possibility to force the update-request to Firebase? I found nothing in the documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

wuhuuuu! I found a solution:

I'm reloading the user object when I acutally need it and after the request was successful I'm updating my views!

```
   private void fillUserViews(NavigationView navigationView) {
      final View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
      final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
      auth.getCurrentUser()
            .reload()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {

               @Override
               public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                  FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

                  ImageView avatarVIew = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.img_avatar);
                  picasso.load(user.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(avatarVIew);
                  TextView userName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
                  userName.setText(user.getDisplayName());
               }
            });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to save the credentials in the `firebaseDatabase` as `node` for each user separately  and **save the username and profile Image there** that will update your view as soon as the data is changed in database, if proper listeners are set.
i.e

[image]

Comment: I also considered using FirebaseDatabase for this. But basically I wanted to try it out with ` UserProfileChangeRequest`

Comment: Hope you found the solution :)

Comment: If it still cause problem try to do directly with `ChildEventListeners`

Comment: thanks! At the moment, the simple solution I posted above is fine for me... thanks for your support!